# How do I replace a special character in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I looked in the [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) library method (.replace), and I am trying to parse all the special characters in a pandas data frame. Meaning for a special character = '½', I am pulling the data as this:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://feeds.donbest.com/ScoresWebApplication/servicePage.jsp?    type=SCHED&leagueId=0&schedDate=20081217&subscr=1'
data = pd.read_html(url)
```

I need to preserve the number and just replace this '½' with a 0.5 when trying this piece of code gets me this:

```
data[1].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='½',value=0.5)
```

It replaces the full data from 172½ for 0.5 instead of preserving its number like this 172.5.

Comment: the regex is returning True for a match and then replacing the entire thing.  You'll need to run an `apply`, identify when it matches, when it does: find the integer part and add it to 0.5.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (just change `0.5` to `'.5'`):

```
data[1].replace(regex=True,inplace=True,to_replace='½',value='.5')
```

First of all, you want the replacement value to be a string, not an number. Secondly, you mean to replace `'½'` with `'.5'`, not `'0.5'`.

Comment: Hey thank you so much I tried that at first, but didn't reference the table so it throw a error. Because I was trying to do it for the data frame, but I found a way to reference all the tables, so it finds all the tables and changes it in the fly. By doing a for loop. So I tried other stuff, read, looked videos and I was not getting the answer. Have a great day wherever you are.